# Why is this a tag being underlined?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using this A tag to create a bunch of different clickable items. After clicking one, if you hover over items, the original will be underlined. I've been trying a lot of different things and nothing is stopping the underlining. It's not under active, visited or hover but it seems to be a mixture of these

I used SASS preprocessor and bootstrap 3. A live link is here:

http://jsbin.com/yavafenasi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="search_options">


          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=24768" target="_blank" class="search_results">
           <div>
              <h3>Stuff 1</h3>
              <p>words</p>
           </div>
          </a>


          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatbread" target="_blank" class="search_results">
           <div>
            <h3>stuff 2</h3>
            <p>words</p>
           </div>
          </a>

          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bread" target="_blank" class="search_results">
           <div>
            <h3>stuff3</h3>
            <p>words</p>
           </div>
          </a>


      </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!--row-->
    </div>
    <!--container-->



</body>
</html>
```

SCSS preprocessed:

```
.search_results
{
    > div
    {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        padding:1px 0px 2px 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border: 1px grey;
        border-radius: 2px;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: black;
    }

    p, h3
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    h3:hover, p:hover, &:hover, h3:active, p:active, &:active, div:hover, div:active, &:visited, p:visited, h3:visited
    {
        text-decoration: none !important;

    }
}
```

CSS compiled and minified:

```
.search_results>div{margin-bottom:25px;padding:1px 0px 2px 4px;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow:0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);border:1px grey;border-radius:2px;text-decoration:none !important;color:black}.search_results p,.search_results h3{text-decoration:none}.search_results h3:hover,.search_results p:hover,.search_results:hover,.search_results h3:active,.search_results p:active,.search_results:active,.search_results div:hover,.search_results div:active,.search_results:visited,.search_results p:visited,.search_results h3:visited{text-decoration:none !important}
```

Comment: It comes from Bootstrap’s scaffolding.less, line 58, rule `a:focus, a:hover`. Have you inspected the element using the dev tools?

Comment: Another observation is that you used `h3:visited` and the `h3` does not have such pseudo class

Comment: I believe that h3 is inheriting a tags attributes, no? Focus fixed it!

Comment: Try this  a:focus, a:hover { text-decoration: none;}

Comment: try my css, may be this will help you

Comment: @munchschair No, an element like `h3` can inherit property _values_ from a parent element, such as an `a`, but not properties is does not have by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.search_results>div{margin-bottom:25px;padding:1px 0px 2px 4px;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow:0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);border:1px grey;border-radius:2px;text-decoration:none !important;color:black}.search_results p,.search_results h3{text-decoration:none}.search_results h3:hover,.search_results p:hover,.search_results:hover,.search_results h3:active,.search_results p:active,.search_results:active,.search_results div:hover,.search_results div:active,.search_results:visited,.search_results p:visited,.search_results h3:visited{text-decoration:none !important}


/*Add this to your css*/
a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited, a:focus {
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
 
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="search_options">
          
          
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=24768" target="_blank" class="search_results">
           <div>
              <h3>Stuff 1</h3>
              <p>words</p>
           </div>
          </a>
       
       
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatbread" target="_blank" class="search_results">
           <div>
            <h3>stuff 2</h3>
            <p>words</p>
           </div>
          </a>
       
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bread" target="_blank" class="search_results">
           <div>
            <h3>stuff3</h3>
            <p>words</p>
           </div>
          </a>
          
          
      </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!--row-->
    </div>
    <!--container-->
 
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Focus of anchor tag `<a>` is creating issue here,

```
a:focus, a:hover {
    color: #23527c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is the final code:

http://jsbin.com/wejehazoxe/1/edit?html,css,js,output

https://codepen.io/eirenaios/pen/GmmxBZ

---

**And you are removing underline from h3 but it is coming from anchor tag  so your SCSS will be :**

```
    .search_results {
 > div {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 1px 0px 2px 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: black;
 }
 p,
 h3 {
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 &:focus {
  text-decoration: none !important;
 }
    &:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
 }
    &:active {
  text-decoration: none !important;
 }
}
```

---

Here is the screenshot of inspected element of anchor tag which creating underline.

[image]